# Get Value From ASM (Assembly 64-bit) C++

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, linker-errors, masm

I am having problems with Assembly & C++, I was just playing around and learning how to use Assembly in C++ but I couldn't seem to be able to get a function in asm to return the value I wanted it to.
My C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();

int main()
{
    cout << GetValueFromASM();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

And my asm code in another file:

```
.code
GetValueFromASM proc
    move eax, 489
    ret
GetValueFromASM endp

end
```

The errors I recieve are

```
Error2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals    
Error1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol GetValueFromASM referenced in function main
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 & and masm for the assembly & I selected x64 in the Configuration Manager, just some extra info there.

I would be very thankful for any help as I am new to asm.

Comment: It is probably easier if you use [inline assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f7adz6y.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I was using that before & and it is much more suited to my level, I will probably switch back to that now that you have mentioned that.

Comment: try to compile(assemble) the assembly source file alone to get the .OBJ file of this .asm file and then add this obj in your linker input files

Comment: You might need to add a leading underscore to your label (some systems do that) and/or make it globally visible using `PUBLIC GetValueFromASM` directive.

Comment: As Jester said, you need to have `_GetValueFromASM proc` if you want to call `GetValueFromASM`. That's the cdecl name decoration.

Comment: On a side note, you should be returning the value in `RAX`. `EAX` is a 32-bit register.

Comment: @Ferruccio on a side note, `EAX` is the low 32 bits of `RAX`, and if you set `EAX`, the top 32 bits are automatically cleared. Also, `int` is still just 32 bits. So that's fine.

Comment: @Jester - you're right. I was thinking of 64-bit ints. Different model.

Comment: Windows doesn't use leading underscores for 64-bit code, so you definitely don't want `_GetValueFromASM proc` for x64.  Jester might be right about `PUBLIC`, though, if the symbol isn't exported by default.   (And BTW, `mov eax, 489` is still the right way to return that value even as a uint64_t if you want; writing EAX implicitly zero-extends into RAX.  `mov rax, 489` would have an identical effect, but take more bytes of machine code.)

Answer (score 0):

**For x86 only**

#### One way

You have to change this:

```
extern "C" int GetValueFromASM();
```

to his:

```
extern "C" int __stdcall GetValueFromASM();
```

#### Another way

Or in asm-file define this

```
.model flat, c
```

instead of this

```
.model flat, stdcall
```

Comment: The question claims it was built as 64-bit.  There is no `stdcall` vs `cdecl` difference in x64, or difference in how symbol names are decorated.  If this was the solution to your problem, you must have been using 32-bit code, which is a different thing.  (Unfortunately the question is not tagged [x86-64])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).